# Memory bandwidth test on Nvidia GPU's

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I tried to use the code posted by nvidia and do a memory bandwidth test but i got some surprising results

Program used is here : https://developer.nvidia.com/content/how-optimize-data-transfers-cuda-cc

On a Desktop (with MacOS)

```
Device: GeForce GT 650M
Transfer size (MB): 16

Pageable transfers
Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 4.053219
Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 5.707841

Pinned transfers
Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 6.346621
Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 6.493052
```

On a Linux server :

```
Device: Tesla K20c
Transfer size (MB): 16

Pageable transfers
Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 1.482011
Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 1.621912

Pinned transfers
Host to Device bandwidth (GB/s): 1.480442
Device to Host bandwidth (GB/s): 1.667752
```

BTW i do not have the root privilege..

I am not sure why its less on the tesla device.. Can anyone point out what would be the reason ?

Comment: Could you give us more information on your software (CUDA version, driver version)? I have the same GT 650M GPU on my laptop, but the bandwidth returned by the test program is much higher for me (`~6.5` and `~10.4` GB/s respectively). I tested this with CUDA 5.0, Linux 64-bit, drivers 319.17.

Comment: Also you can have either DDR3 or GDDR5 for the GT 650M, which has its importance.

Comment: CUDA version is CUDA 5.0 on both, both are 64 bit systems.. @BenC my problem is not with the GT 650M.. it is rather with the Tesla k20c.. i dont understand why that is slower than the GT 650M ?

Comment: My point is that there may be reasons other than the hardware specifications, even though these play the main role.

Comment: The bandwidth could be limited by the available/connected PCIe lanes. These can be checked with `lspci -vv`. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393/how-to-check-how-many-lanes-are-used-by-the-pcie-card) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is most likely that the GPU in your server isn't in a 16 lane PCI express slot. I would expect a PCI-e v2.0 device like the K20C to be able to achieve between 4.5-5.5Gb/s peak throughput on a reasonably specified modern server (probably about 6Gb/s on a desktop system an integrated PCI-e controller). Your results look like you are hosting the GPU in a 16x slot with only 8 or even 4 active lanes.

There can be also other factors at work, like CPU-IOH affinity, which can increase the number of "hops" between the PCI-e bus hosting the GPU and the processor and its memory running the test). But providing further analysis would require more details about the configuration and hardware of the server, which is really beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sagar Masuti: If this is reasonable, could you accept it, just so we can clear this question off the unanswered question queue for the CUDA tag?

Comment: Do you mean that you have tested the k20c to give 4.5/5.5 Gb/s ? If yes, I will gladly accept the answer and ask server admin to check for the issue.

Comment: @SagarMasuti: I haven't tested a K20c. I have tested an older C2050 Fermi Tesla on a Sandy Bridge EP host, which is a PCI-e 2.0 device/host and got around 5.5 Gb/s. And I have tested a PCI-e 3.0 Kepler device and got around 12.0 Gb/s on an Ivy Bridge host. Here is a link to [someone else's K20c results](http://labs.beatcraft.com/en/index.php?CUDA5%2FCentOS6.4) showing about 6Gb/s on an Ivy Bridge host. So your numbers are low and it is likely to be a host installation or configuration issue. That is about all I can tell you.

Answer (score -1):

A quick view of [Tesla K20c spec](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/564/tesla-k20c.html) and [GT 650M spec](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/550/geforce-gt-650m-mac-edition.html) can clarify things. We see that PCIe interface of the Tesla has version **2.0** which is [slower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) vs the GT PCIe interface which is **3.0**. Although the Tesla has more resources in terms of Memory and Memory Bus those two parameters would **limit** the **Memory Bandwidth**. Therefore the Tesla may issue more memory instructions than the GT but they stall because of the PCIe interface.

Of course this may not be the only reason, but for details I would explore the architectures of both cards as I saw small difference (at least in the naming).

Edit#1: Referring the comments below apparently you can achieve PCIe 3.0 speed on PCIe 2.0 boards. Check [this](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/index.html#pcie-30)

Comment: He is using a [GT 650M](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/550/geforce-gt-650m-mac-edition.html), you should adapt your answer to the proper hardware.

Comment: @KiaMorot well that could be one reason.. is it expected the rate i am getting with the PCIe 2.0 ? or its higher ? if that u know otherwise i will check it out..

Comment: @SagarMasuti this is at least the most fastest logical reason. But it depends on how deep you want to dig. To my knowledge I don't think there is such a thing "expected rate". NVIDIA engineers give theoretical bandwidth and you see real bandwidth. There might be other smaller reasons which you could explore with more detail looking at the architectures of the cards as I see a small difference (at least in the naming). Perhaps there some performance is lost.

Comment: @SagarMasuti: concerning PCIe 3.0, you can read [**this**](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/kepler-tuning-guide/index.html#pcie-30). This also explains the differences between pageable and pinned memory transfers on your Kepler GPU.